# Есть ли готовые примеры выдачи ошибок компиляторами?

Tags: java, c#, c++, компилятор, компоновщик

Для текстового редактора создается модуль, позволяющий делать внешний запуск на компиляцию/линковку/сборку файлов разных типов:

- Borland C++,
- GNU C++,
- Delphi,
- Java,
- MS C#,
- Python
- и др.

Вывод внешних инструментов перехватывается. С помощью RegExp-выражений из сообщений об ошибках извлекается информация в каком *файле/строке/колонке* проблема. При необходимости выполняется навигация к проблемному месту.

**Как/где найди примеры того, как выглядят "сообщения об ошибках", для максимального числа компиляторов/линтеров/билдеров/...?**

Например, для Python мне такой пример известен - сообщение имеет вид

`File "C:\work-folder\work-file.py", line 123`

Comment: Общего формата сообщения об ошибке нет, разумеется. Для каждой конкретной версии компилятора смотрите в документацию по каждому из компиляторов.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что у каждого внеш.инструмента будет свой формат сообщения. Предусмотрены разные шаблоны для анализа.

Comment: Хуже того, форматы сообщения об ошибках могут меняться от версии к версии :( Так что у вас достаточно сложное задание. Удачи вам! Надеюсь, у кого-то найдутся наработки.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Можно посмотреть на аналоги, например. Основные известные мне являются лишь основами, а конкретные матчеры поставляются в виде плагинов к ним.

Поскольку я пользовался в основном Sublime Text и Atom, примеры про них.

- [AtomLinter](http://atomlinter.github.io/) (плагины для анализа перечислены прямо там)
- [Atom-Build](https://atombuild.github.io/) (провайдеры сборки и поиска ошибок перечислены прямо там)
- [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3) (часть плагинов разрабатывается [в этой организации](https://github.com/SublimeLinter) на гитхабе)

Comment: В каком файле в репо Atom-Build можно увидеть шаблоны для реации на ошибки?

Comment: @kvichans то ядро, надо смотреть провайдеров. Например, [вот регулярки для Elixir](https://github.com/AtomBuild/atom-build-elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir.js#L26).

Comment: Регулярки понятные, в моем коде их можно использовать сразу, так как именованные подгруппы уже есть и даже их названия совпадают. Поясните, почему у ключа errorMatch может быть список из нескольких значений. В целом, это маленький кусочек того, что нужно.

Comment: @kvichans там [целая история](https://github.com/noseglid/atom-build/pull/131), закончившаяся пулреквестом. Поизучайте, процесс разработки открыт. Можете даже зайти к ним в чатик и поспрашивать.